# value for data() would be ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of article. I filter the list on the client with jquery.

The following function works really fine, the only part is, that the data() would be ignored. the the searchgewerk is per default 0 or got another value which exist in the list.

```
function filterArticlelist( searchterm, searchgewerk )
{
    if(searchterm.length > 1) {
        if( searchgewerk == 0 )
        {
            var match = $( 'tr.data-row:contains("' + searchterm + '")' );
            var nomatch = $( 'tr.data-row:not(:contains("' + searchterm + '"))' );

        }
        else
        {
//When searchgewerk is not 0 then i reach this else part. With console.log() the correct searchgewerk value would be logged.
            var match = $( 'tr.data-row:contains("' + searchterm + '")').data( "gewerk",searchgewerk );
            var nomatch = $( 'tr.data-row:not(:contains("' + searchterm + '"))' ).data( "gewerk",searchgewerk );
        }

        match
            .addClass( 'selected' )
            .css( "display", "" );

        nomatch
            .css( "display", "none");
    }
    else
    {
        $('tr.data-row').css("display", "");
        $('tr.data-row').removeClass('selected');

    }
}
```

Where is my error? Maybe did i think in a wronk way? I have also tried hasData(), but it also doesent work.

Thanks for your help

This is the view for every tr, its build with TWIG:

```
{% for data in ObjektArtikel %}
                    {% if loop.index0 is not even %}
                        {% set background = "trAvailableArticleBackground" %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% set background = "trAvailableArticleNoneBackground" %}
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="data-row trAvailableArticle {{ background }}" id="{{ data.artikelnummer }}" data-gewerk="{{ data.su_gewerk }}">
                        <td class="tdArticleNumber">
                            {{ data.artikelnummer }} - {{ data.su_gewerk }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="tdArticle">{{ data.artikel }}</td>
                        <td class="tdArticleDescription">{{ data.beschreibung }}</td>
                        <td class="tdArticleEinheit">{{ data.einheit }}</td>
                        <td><img class="addArticle" src="/bundles/mbsallgemein/images/add.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: How do you know the `.data()` part is ignored?

Comment: because, the matched list is the same like in the section where searchgewerk==0

Comment: Well, yeah, you're using the same selector in both cases. What do you expect the `.data()` call to do, filter the results somehow?

Comment: When searchgewerk == 0 then it should search all TR which contains the searchterm. When searchgewerk are not 0, then it should view all TR which contain searchterm and tr data-gewerk  == searchgewerk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to filter on the `data-gewerk` attribute, you may be looking for something like this:

```
$('tr.data-row[data-gewerk="' + searchgewerk + '"]:contains("' + searchterm + '")')
```

This:

```
.data(key, value)
```

is a setter, it doesn't filter anything.